# Remain on same page same tab after files are uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have registration process having three tabs. On the second tab I have the Browse and Upload Documents feature. I want to stay on the same page same tab with all the data maintain so that the user can proceed to third tab after the files are uploaded and need to display the return data (names of the files which have been uploaded). I have searched but couldn't find the appropriate solution so far.
The for loop below the form tag displays the names of all the files which have been uploaded when the data returns to the view from the controller as i m using codeigniter.

View.php

```
<form id="fileupload" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_file/upload_it'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-warning">
        <span>Browse</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" class="upload" />
    </div>
    <input id="uploadFile" style="width: 160px; margin-top: 30px;float: left;height: 34px;" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
    <button style="padding: 4px;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
    </button>
</form>    

<div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <?php $upload_data=0; if($upload_data != ''):?>
         <?php for($i=0;$i<count($upload_data);$i++) { ?>
             <span><?php echo $upload_data[$i]['file_name'];?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

In Js to get number of files selected.

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function (){
     var files = document.getElementById("uploadBtn").files;
     if(files.length==1)
    {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
    }
    if(files.length>1)
    {
        document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = files.length+' Files Selected';
    }
};
</script>
```

controller.php

```
<?php
class Upload_file extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    function upload_it()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $config['upload_path'] = 'application/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');
        $data['upload_data'] = '';
        if (!$this->upload->do_multi_upload('files'))
        {
            $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        }
        else
        { 
             $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
        }   
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('registration', $data);
    }
}?>
```

Comment: submit form via ajax and move to tab 3 once you get success response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to give a hidden iframe as a `target` to your `<form>` element to avoid a page reload ..

#### Add this iframe to your HTML:

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

#### Include attribute `target="upload_target"` in your `form` element:

```
  <form target="upload_target" ...
```

Comment: I didnt get ur answer :(

Comment: Thanx it worked now. Before i didnt get about target.

Comment: Now one more question is that do i need to load header and registration in the controller again or not? And one more thing the files names are not coming any solution?

Comment: Access file name using $_FILES["file"]["name"]

Comment: In the controller i have array `$data['upload_data']` which i m passing to the view as `$this->load->view('registration',$data)` and using this array in for loop i m echoing the file names this code worked as far this feature was in the seperate view but when i integrate it its not working :(
I am not clear how i can access the file names using the code `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: Print out `$_FILES` array in your controller and check if you are getting valid file names

Comment: yes i m getting i have done it. the files name do come if i use the `for loop code for printing names` above the `<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">` area and removing the iframe but it doesn't come if i place it in `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">` and use iframe.

Comment: Wana share onething when i remove the `style:display:none;` from the iframe it remains on same page and load the whole page inside the iframe containing name of the files which have been uploaded